# MEAN Stack, Why does express keep routing with a # in the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean

Trying to used to back end stuff. Started off by following the thinkster guide on express. Was wondering if someone could clear some stuff up for me.

Firstly, I understand that the front-end and back-end routing are different. To my understanding the front end routing is for the user experience (going from page to page), and the back end routing (e.g router.get(~~~)) is used for API calls and interacting with database stuff. Why is it that

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Is whats initially loading the first page?

Secondly, my front end routing looks like this

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}
]);
```

However, whenever I run my server and go to localhost:3000, it automatically puts me to localhost:3000/#/ and serves the content there. I know the thinkster guide uses inline templates but I am trying to just use seperate html files, and its still doing that.

If anyone could clear up my confusion, Id be very grateful! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's angular's default behaviour of routing urls.

To remove the hashtag from your urls, you will need to set angular's $locationProvider's html5Mode to true

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',$locationProvider, 
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}
])
```

Check out this [article](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer < 10 does not support the Html5 history api. The # is in the url the enable the user to go forward and backwards using browser buttons. Removing it breaks this functionality in IE < 10. Until more people are using 10+, it's recommend that you leave it in.